# Detect whether template parameter is cv-qualified

Tags: c++, templates

I have an existing code that uses an 'Array' class to represent a 1D array. This is a base template class implemented as

```
// Forward declaration
template<typename T> class Array;

// Implementation of 'const' Array class:
template<typename T>
class Array<const T>
{
  // ...
};
```

This class has a read-only interface, so for example the element access operator is only present in its const version:

```
const T& operator[](unsigned int i) const
```

Then there's a class derived from `Array`, which allows modification of its member data:

```
template<typename T>
class Array<T> : public Array<const T>
```

The derived class supplies

```
T& operator[](unsigned int i)
```

etc. in addition to methods inherited from parent. My task is to perform some refactoring of the code to extend the functionality of `Array`. While thinking about my options, I would like to know if there's a way of detecting the cv-qualifier of `Array`'s template parameter, so that I could for example have

```
template <typename T>
class Array<T>
{
  public:

    enum { is_const = template_param_is_const<T>::value; }

    // ...
};
```

and `is_const` would have different values for `Array<T>` and `Array<const T>`.

Suggestions for any improvements of the existing implementation that would preserve the distinction between `Array<T>` and `Array<const T>` and the above described behavior are also welcome.

Comment: [`std::is_const`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_const)?

Comment: Breaking the Liskov substitution principle.

Comment: @Holt: thanks for the remark. I should have looked for that myself ...

Comment: @Alf: could you please elaborate? How does the code above break the Liskov substitution principle?

Comment: what are you trying to do? In this case, you could declare `operator []` as `const` even if `T` isn't; then if `T` is inherently const the reference will be forbidden from being modified. Do you explicitly need the method not to be const when the template type isn't?

Comment: @FrancescoDondi: if I understand you correctly, you're suggesting that the child class has `T& operator[](unsigned int i) const`? Then I have no way of modifying the class data from outside, which renders the class useless. I don't think I can have both `T& operator [](unsigned int i) const` and `const T& operator [](unsigned int i) const` in the same class (that would be overloading on return type, wouldn't it?). I'm not sure I understand what you meant.

Comment: @MartinVymazal: How it breaks the LSP: it's not true that `Array<int>` **is a** constant (immutable) array, yet that's what's modeled via the inheritance. Whether that can break code depends very much on the details. I found it difficult to construct an example where code would break, but if it were me I'd change the design anyway. Side note: you will probably have to make the `Array<T>` a primary template in order for this to compile. It can't be a specialization.

Comment: @FrancesoDondi: you asked what am I trying to achieve. I need to make Array a policy-based class where the internal implementation (data storage etc.) will depend on policy. Doing this with the current inheritance hierarchy seems to be a bit difficult. I'm thinking about having only one `Array<T>` where all non-const methods would be disabled when T is not const. Hence the question about `is_const` member above. The trouble is that I can't think of better way of disabling the non-const methods than placing `static_assert(is_const, " .... ")` in all of them - tedious and not very elegant.

Comment: @Alf: actually, the code compiles - it's existing code that I'm just supposed to modify. You said you would change the design. Could you at least briefly suggest how? Thanks for the remark regarding Liskov substitution principle - I see what you mean and agree with you.

Comment: @MartinVymazal actually you could modify the class data even with `const`. You couldn't do it *inside* the method -but no one can tell you what or what not to do with the returned reference; you can modify the object to your heart's content. `arr[0]=5` works with `[]` declared as `const` because it's not modifying anything, `=` is. Unless, of course, `T` is itself const-qualified; in which case you cannot modify it (because `=` fails, independently from `[]`). So it seems to me you can do what you want without any need to have a specialized 'const' class at all!